# (MonetDB) available main-memory

Tags: monetdb

I'm testing MonetDB in CentOS for a BI database, and during inserts, reaching 8 million records, my database has crashed with the message "database 'olap1' (9111) has crashed (dumped core)" (from log).
In the log I saw that monetdb is only using 4gb of memory ("Found 4.000 GiB available main-memory.") and my test PC has 8GB of memory.

Is there any way for MonetDB to use more memory, since I do not use any other application on the server?

Comment: AFAIK MonetDB is pretty greedy with memory, meaning it will take up as much as it can. Can you provide some more information about your setup, specifically what version of MonetDB are you running? Did you start it with any extra arguments? Which version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: I'm Using MonetDB 5 server v11.25.5 "Dec2016-SP1" and CentOS 6.8. To run the monetdb I just use "monetdb start /path/to/mydbfarm" and to access the database "mclient -u rp -d olap1". Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your usage. The only thing I can think of (although I admit it is unlikely), is that maybe you are using a 32 bit CentOS installation? 

Other than that I would recommend to update your MonetDB version (Dec2016-SP3 is the current version, and probably sometime next week SP4 will be released).

Also what worries me is that your server is crashing. If you can find specifically why, we would appreciate a bug report at our [bugzilla](https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: What I mean with the last sentence, is that if you can find a minimal way to reproduce the crash (e.g. it crashes when I execute the query <...>) we would very much like to hear about it.

Comment: Well, actually my CentOS is 32bits and in that case MonetDB only uses 4Gb. I tried with Dec2016-SP3 and the same thing happens, so I'll try CentOS 64Bits. Thank you for your help! :)